# When and why is the product of a matrix and a vector equal to zero?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I have a matrix $X$ where its columns are independent, which vectors  $u \in \Bbb R^p$ makes $X.u = 0$? Is it $u = 0$?

Comment: When you do the multiplication and you get the zero vector? When the vector is orthogonal to each row of the matrix? What kind of answer are you looking for?

Comment: There is no general rule when $Ax=0$ for some matrix $A$ and a vector $x$. It depends on $A$ and $x$. If $A$ is invertible ($\det A \neq 0$) we can say $Ax=0 \Leftrightarrow x=0$ for example. But in the current formulation it is unclear what exactly your question is.

Comment: Sorry I am being unclear. I mean, for example, what if I have a matrix X where columns are linearly independent, then which vectors u (\in R^p) satisfy X.u = 0?

Comment: @Anonymous That is an important bit of information. If the rows are linearly independent they form a basis for $\Bbb R^p$. Thus $Xu$ is a linear combination of a basis and hence $Xu =0$ if and only if $u=0$.

Comment: @GhostAmarth, no, it is not stated that the matrix is square.

Comment: @Alexey Oh right! Wasn't paying attention...

Comment: Hm this question looks like part of a question that I addressed in a comment and that was just deleted

Answer (score 1):

Although the question lacks some information I'll try to give an answer to what I understand the question is. For any matrix $X$ we have $Xu = 0$ for $u=0$ as one calculates directly. The interesting part is, what other vectors $u\neq 0$ satisfy $Xu=0$?

If $X\in\Bbb R^{p\times p}$ (a square matrix) we can say the following:

If the rows are linearly independent, then so are the columns. Let $X=(b_1, \ldots, b_p)$, so $b_i\in\Bbb R^p$ are the columns. Since they are linearly independent and $p$ many, they form a basis for $\Bbb R^p$.
Now for some vector $u=(u_1, \ldots, u_p)\in \Bbb R^p$ we have
$$
Xu = u_1b_1+\ldots + u_p b_p.
$$
The expression on the right side is a linear combination of basis vectors representing the vector $Xu$. The coefficients are thus uniquely determined and $u_1b_1+\ldots+u_pb_p=0 \Leftrightarrow u_1=\ldots=u_p = 0 \Leftrightarrow u=0$. So $Xu=0\Leftrightarrow u=0$.

If $X$ is not a square matrix this doesn't have to be true, for example:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}1 & -1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a \\ a\end{pmatrix} = 0
$$
for all $a\in \Bbb R$.

In general the kernel (null space) $\ker X = \{u\in\Bbb R^p : Xu=0\}$ (the elements which get mapped to $0$) is an important tool when studying matrices. You can easily verify $\ker X$ to be a vector space and find plenty of information on the internet about it; especially on this site.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Really appreciate!